# problems with paste event and iframe on internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, internet-explorer-7, paste

I've got a WYSIWYG editor, based on JqueryRTE (code.google.com/p/lwrte), which uses iframe as a main object and enables a few means of formatting. Still I need to sanitize pasted text, because users tend to paste formatted text from MS Word or Openoffice.org documents, and the biggest part of that formatting is not supported. 
I use the following function to attach 'paste' event to iframe document :

```
 function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
                    if (el.addEventListener) {
                        el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
                    } else if (el.attachEvent){
                        el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
                    }
                }
```

And call it as follows :

```
bindEvent(iframe.contentWindow.document, 'paste', function () { cleanPastedText(); });
```

It works just fine on FF and latest IE versions, whilst I cannot get the event handler called on IE7. I studied bindEvent with debugger, it gets attachEvent executed. I even tried binding handler to the main form, but there has still been no result. Can you please guide me, what is the possible reason, and is it possible at all to catch "paste" event using IE7 if the text is pasted to elements other than input or textarea? Is it possible, that the event actually gets fired somewhere in iframe child element, but is not propagated to parent node? Iframe inner html is roughly as follows :

```
<html><head></head><body>here comes some text and some pasted text and other blahblah</body></html>
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that window and document objects do not fire paste event on older versions of IE (< IE9). Corresponding article at quirksmode :
 [quirksmode - cut,copy,paste](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html)

In addition, the event does not propagate outside iframe inner document, so, in my case, I had to assign event listener to <body> or to <html> element of iframe document. The resulting code line :

```
bindEvent(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], 'paste', function () { cleanPastedText(); });
```

Since the latter has been done, it works like a charm. Hopefully, this answer will be useful for other SO users.